# Can it be considered that a frame-dependent crosshair is a flaw?

Tags: game-design, anti-cheat, frame-rate

I still play counter strike 1.6/CSS these days, and as you know, when shots are fired, the crosshair expands.

When the frame rate drops, this crosshair animation is also affected by the frame rate.

Can it be considered like a programming/design flaw or is it like so for anti-cheat reasons ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of animation you are talking about and how it's affected?

Comment: I believe when a shot is fired the crosshair expands and returns to normal after set amount of time. I don't remember the crosshair being animated in any other sort of way.

Comment: To expand on Ray's point, the 4 lines comprising the cross go outwards to form a bigger crosshair to make it harder to aim. This means literally firing everywhere becomes inefficient to aim well.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: The purpose of the expanding crosshair is *not* to make it harder to aim, but to represent that the weapon is becoming less accurate. It feeds back to the user, not depends on the user to create an effect.

Comment: I stand corrected. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you don't like *can* be considered a flaw. Who's to decide what is and what isn't?

As it happens, pretty much all your graphics are frame-dependent. You can't draw something on the screen in between frames, by definition. The only possible way around that is to use some sort of hardware overlay system but I don't know how well supported they are these days.

Comment: I just thought it would have some anti cheat matter...

Answer (score 2):

The crosshair animation is only a general indicator. All the physics takes place on the game server and thus is totally independent of the client's frame rate.

Comment: Have you already/ever played Counter Strike on a slow/laggy machine ?

Comment: @jokoon: Why yes, I have. And it doesn't matter how you feel about that experience. It is a fact that the server performs physics, not the client.

Comment: Actually @DeadMG, the client handles the recoil, the server processes the collisions afterwards. But yes, recoil is deterministic, and runs the same way no matter the framerate.

Comment: attackinghobbo: well I played a lot, and I can tell that having a slower computer makes a player spray much less efficiently. I don't really know if that's a biased feeling for some reason, but even though, it should have been fixed...

Comment: @jokoon: It probably does, because spraying effectively relies on moving the crosshair down as the recoil moves the gun up, which is a less effective reaction on a slower computer.